# How to get all of name route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I going to get all of route name in laravel project.

For example :

I have this route :

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('homeNameRoute');
```

I want get homeNameRoute !!!

tanks.

Comment: Where you want to get it ??

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`currentRouteName()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#accessing-the-current-route) method:

```
Route::currentRouteName();
```

This will return you `homeNameRoute` when you are on the `/home` page.

Comment: Tanks, but I want all of the name routes and not just current route !!!

Comment: @MohammadIlbeygi you just want to see the list of all routes in your app? Then just use `php artisan route:list` command.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Look into the source of the command and you will have an idea on how to get route names. You can get all route with something like `resolve('Illuminate\Routing\Router')->getRoutes()` and then filter the only data you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.. using Route Facade

```
$routes = Route::getRoutes();
dd($routes);
```

or try use Artisan::call

```
\Artisan::call('route:list');
\Aritisan::output();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be helpful:

```
$route_name = [];

foreach (Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() as $route) {
    $action = $route->getAction();
    if (array_key_exists('as', $action)) {
        $route_name[] = $action['as'];
    }
}
dd($route_name);
```

Comment: hey @Shree Sthapit, can you tell me what did you here......please it can be helpful for me..

Comment: what did you do here

Comment: @TanvirAhmed I have placed this code in my controller in order to list the routes and manage ACL for the roles and users.